# What is the width of a Merkle tree

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to apply hyperledger fabric to my project so studying it.

And I'm facing the config block in json data and but got so confused at this part.

```
"BlockDataHashingStructure": {
  "mod_policy": "Admins",
  "value": {
    "width": 4294967295
  },
  "version": "0"
},
```

The official document says, "This value specifies the width of that Merkle tree"
but I don't get what the width of Merkle tree is.
Is there anybody who can explain me easily the meaning of the width of Merkle tree?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer but I'm not a specialist of merkle trees (So it would be nice if a specialist reviews my answer!!). The width of the tree is the number of bytes or arrays of bytes you concatenate together as input to the hash for the next tree level.

Usually we see binary trees => each node of the trees have 2 childrens. So the width would be 2 (or 16 for 2 bytes, I dont know sorry).

But have a look at the MD6 algorithm which uses the merkle tree. The tree is not "binary", each node has 4 children:

[image: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD6]

The value 4294967295 is the max value of uint32. So the tree will have the maximum width size. It would result in a tree with only 2 levels: The level 0 "containing" all bytes of the block and the level 1 "containing" the hash of the concatained bytes of level 0.

It seems that fabric doesn't support "real" merkle trees yet (with more than 2 levels)

The tree construction seems to be made by using the function Bytes (see https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/13447bf5ead693f07285ce63a1903c5d0d25f096/protos/common/block.go)

```
// Bytes returns a deterministically serialized version of the BlockData
// eventually, this should be replaced with a true Merkle tree construction,
// but for the moment, we assume a Merkle tree of infinite width (uint32_max)
// which degrades to a flat hash
func (b *BlockData) Bytes() []byte {
return util.ConcatenateBytes(b.Data...)
}
```

I don't know if a multilevel merkle tree would be useful in hyperledger fabric. My understanding of using a merkle tree is to simplify the verification of the presence of a transaction inside a block. But in hyperledger, you dont need to simplify this because the peers maintain a state database alongside the blockchain (levelDB or couchDB).
But I can be wrong.

Comment: But I am still wordering as I ams not that used to cs concepts.. you mean 4,294,967,295 is the maximum value of uint32, as it's converted into standard hexadecimal? In the picture above, for example, a leaf node of the lv.0 will have a uint32 value then its number of bit will be 32 then. So a middle node of lv.1 will have width of 128 bits(32 x 4), then? Am i understanding your explanation?

Comment: "The width of the tree is the number of bytes or arrays of bytes you concatenate together as input to the hash for the next tree level", you mean the width of tree is the sum of bytes of all leaf node data (which are blocks) to calculate the root hash?